# axios.get request returning GET,HEAD as response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using React, Redux, Node, Axios and working on adding pagination to my request using mongoose-paginate-v2. My axios.get looks like this:

```
export const getUsers = (page) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.get(`${USERS_ENDPOINT}/${page}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${USERS_TOKEN}`,
          "token": cookies.get('token')
        }
      })
      .then(async response => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USERS,
          payload: response.data.list,
          page: page
        });
      }).catch(e => { console.log(e); return e })
  }
}
```

and my rest-api function looks like this:

```
app.get('/allusers/:page', auth, (req,res)=>{
  console.log('req',req)
  let log={}
  Object.assign(log,{header:req.headers,body:req.body,query:req.query,params:req.params})
  request(uri,USERS_FILTER,{token: req.header('token'), page:req.params.page
}).then(result => {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }).catch(error => {
    logger.error('log error',{error:error})
    if(error.response.errors[0].message==='Error: 401'){
      res.status(401).send('Not Permitted');
    }else{
      res.status(500).end(); // Or other error handling
    }
  });
  logger.info('users request log',log)
});
```

My backend is working properly when i test it with postman, but when i use my UI to send the request I get status 200 and `GET, HEAD` as response, when using postman I get a tab with my users.
This is a screenshot of my request:
[image]
[image]

[image]

PS: i'm using:

- node v12.6.0
- react v16.6.3
- express v4.16.3

Comment: Show "General" table in chrome dev tools

Comment: @kinduser I cant find the "General" tab on my devtool

Comment: In the headers tab, you have General, Response Headers etc

Comment: `console.log` the result you're sending from the server. Confirm that the server isn't actually erroneously sending "GET, HEAD".

Comment: @kinduser i added another screenshot to the post

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. It's only "options" request, the 'get' request is not even fired.

Comment: @chrispytoes I did that, its not responding at all

Comment: @asma Well then the request must not be going to the correct server, or it's being stopped and sent back by another middleware.

Comment: The outgoing OPTIONS method just ask to the server what kind of request is allowed.
The GET, HEAD is it's anwser.

Comment: I changed my sythax into:
axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${USERS_ENDPOINT}/${page}`,
    })
the request is firing but I cant find a way to pass my token. If i pass it in headers it goes back to OPTIONS request
@kinduser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using the `cors` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
[image]